# Match newline `\n` in ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to understand why the following returns false: (** I should have put "outputs 0" **)

```rb
puts "a\nb" =~ Regexp.new(Regexp.escape("a\nb"), Regexp::MULTILINE | Regexp::EXTENDED)
```

Perhaps someone could explain.

I am trying to generate a Regexp from a multi-line String that will match the String.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`puts` will always return `nil`.

Your code should work fine, albeit lengthy. `=~` returns the position of the match which is 0.

You could also use:

```
"a\nb" =~ /a\sb/m
```

or

```
"a\nb" =~ /a\nb/m
```

Note: The `m` option isn't necessary in this example but demonstrates how it would be used without `Regexp.new`.

Comment: Is there a method that returns a boolean if a String matches a Regexp?

Comment: @Arth You could do this: `!!("a\nb" =~ /a\sb/m)`

Comment: Could do! Surprised there is no built in function in the String or the Regexp class though.

Comment: The option `m` is not needed in either version. Both `\s` and `\n` do match `\n` even without it.

Comment: @undur_gongor I know. I wanted to show that options can be added without using `Regexp.new`.

Comment: @depot: If you make this clear in your answer you'll get my upvote ;-)

Comment: @undur_gongor A smart addition. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry was aware of the option syntax, was generating the Regexp from a String variable, so needed Regexp.new. I just copied out the code and replaced the variable.

Comment: @Arth this is what Regexp#=== does:

    /a/ === 'apple' #=> true

Answer (score 1):

Probably, `puts` caused this

```
1.9.3-194 (main):0 > puts ("a\nb" =~ Regexp.new(Regexp.escape("a\nb"), Regexp::MULTILINE | Regexp::EXTENDED) )
0
=> nil


1.9.3-194 (main):0 > "a\nb" =~ Regexp.new(Regexp.escape("a\nb"), Regexp::MULTILINE | Regexp::EXTENDED)
=> 0
```

Comment: I don't understand, I was questioning why there are no matches.

Comment: matched position 0 was returned

Comment: Ahh, I understand now, guess I misunderstood the =~ operator.